# How to decrease the time loading of google map angular ionic when using window.open

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<a onclick="window.open('https://googl/maps/L3uiWNRPf2n')">
```

Sometimes it opens but it takes too much time.

Sometimes it gives an error message:

```
failed to load to the server : url
```

How can I improve the performance or decrease the loading time?

I am using `angular`, `ionic`, `HTML` and `JavaScript`.

Comment: What's your ping time to the server like?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean ?

Comment: It takes about 8 seconds with black screen until the google map open